# Suggest the regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm using Java. Please help me suggest the expression for this string:

```
"Good" or "(Good]" and "[Bad)" or "Bad"
```

The result expected should be contains ) or ( symbol as: `"(Good]"` , `"[Bad)"`
I'm have tested here https://regex101.com/r/d0l0xw/12 but not working expected.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: `(` contains "(" ; why should the regex match `"(Good]"` rather than just stop at `(` ?

Comment: maybe `"[^"]*[()][^"]*"` ? Please make sure you understand what it does before using it, because your question isn't clear and I could totally misunderstand your need ; for instance if will also match `"...)(..."`

Comment: I have updated my question and added test, please help to suggest regex. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, you right, it working perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"[^"]*[()][^"]*"` (or in Java `\"[^\"]*[()][^\"]*\"`) will match a string starting with `"` and ending with `"` that contains at least one occurence of `(` or `)`.

Explanation :

- `"` matches a literal double-quote
- `[^"]*` matches any number of any characters but a quote ; we use this to signify that there may be any character before and after the bracket, without going over the end of the quote-enclosed string
- `[()]` will match either `(` or `)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can find the regular expression representations somewhere, but you're looking at the following steps:

Good or (Good] String
1) 1 or 0 "("
2) "Good"
3) 1 or 0 "]"

Bad or [Bad) String
1) 1 or 0 "["
2) "BAD"
3) 1 or 0 ")"

Then tie them together with an OR expression.

*Note: Brackets have special representations so you will have to use a specific reg ex for those